# How to resolve Server error in vue.js using localhost

Tags: javascript, vue.js, symfony

I am new in Vuejs,I am working on existing project,whenever i am trying to use "login" module then i am getting following error "Server error",How can i fix this , Here is my code (inside src/common/request.js)

```
  import axios from "axios";
import store from "@/store";

export function request(uri, method, body, headers) {
    
    //alert('i am hereeeee');
    
  const config = {
    method: method.toLowerCase(),
    url: uri,
    data: body,
    headers: { Authorization: "" },
    validateStatus: function (status) {
      return status >= 200 && status < 400;
    },
  };
  if (!config.url.includes("http")) {
    config.baseURL = "/";
  } else {
    config.headers = headers ? headers : {};
  }
  if (uri.indexOf("/api/login") < 0) {
    const token = store.getters.getToken || "";
    config.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + token;
  }
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
     
      
      
    axios(config)
      .then(function (response) {
        resolve(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        if (error.response && error.response.status == 401) {
          //need login
          if (uri.indexOf("/api/login") >= 0) {
            reject(error.response.data);
          }
          store.dispatch("logout");
          window.location.href = "/login";
        }
        if (error.response && error.response.status == 400) {
          reject(error.response.data);
        }
        if (error.response && error.response.status == 500) {
          alert("服務器錯誤，請稍後再試！");
        }
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: The question should be updated to include  the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Yogi i am not getting data even in home page

Comment: "Server error" is surely not the full and exact error message. Also, why is this tagged with Symfony, but does not contain any PHP code?

Comment: Open browser developer tools to inspect the logon request.  What information is sent to the server?  See: [Inspect network activity](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/)